# Does relationship between c.e.set, productive set, immune set, ML-random set exist between sets of class of other level

Tags: set-theory, computational-complexity, computability-theory, algorithmic-randomness

Is relationship between c.e.set, productive set, immune set, ML-random set similar to relationship between polynomial complexity set, polynomial complexity-productive set, P-immune set, P-random set?